# prop.test returning significant p-value but a confidence interval including 0

Tags: proportion

I have been testing the differences in proportions between two groups (A: 10 successes and 22 failures, B: 10 successes and 70 failures). Interestingly, prop.test returns a significant p-value on the 5% level (0.039) but a 95% confidence interval which includes 0.

```
tab <- matrix(c(10,10,22,70), nrow = 2)
tab

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   10   22
[2,]   10   70

prop.test(tab)


2-sample test for equality of proportions with continuity
correction

data:  tab
X-squared = 4.2746, df = 1, p-value = 0.03869
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
-0.01056535  0.38556535
sample estimates:
prop 1 prop 2 
0.3125 0.1250
```

I know prop.test is correcting for continuity using Yate's approach. But it is doing this for both the confidence intervals and the p-value. How can it be that the p-value and the confidence interval give different results?

Comment: Are you sure that you are not just looking at the difference between the proportion ?  A 95% confidence interval for the difference could contain 0.

Comment: Sorry, the set up is correct, as you have it. The fact that the CI includes zero means that the difference between proportions is not significant.

Comment: B has an estimated success probability of 0.125 and A approx. 0.312. On the surface this looks like it could a significant difference.  The sample sizes are only 32 and 80  The OP says that he is using a continuity correction for the binomial.  So the confidence interval is approximate. The p-value is 0.039 not far below 0.05.  All this makes me think that the confidence interval containing 0 is possible even though the test implies  a signifcant difference in proportions. How does prop.test work?

Comment: @MichaelChernick I just came across your note by accident. I'm not sure it was address to me, but in any event, I'm looking at R's help, and it is a Pearson's chi square test statistic with or without Yates's continuity correction. Hope it helps. My take was that the OP didn't see the concept of "including zero is what happens when the difference in proportions can very well be zero based on the data."

Comment: @AntoniParellada My intention was to address you and the OP.  You and I are on the same page but the OP remains silent.

Comment: @MichaelChernick : Thanks for the answer. I'm still struggling though. The null is that the difference is 0. If the 95% confidence interval (of the difference) contains 0, the null cannot be rejected at the 5% level. Put differently: the p-value is > 0.05. I still don't get from your answer how it is possible that the null is not rejected on a 5% level looking at the confidence interval but rejected according to the p value.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem myself. Your question came up as I was googling for explanations. (What I'm saying is that I might not be the utmost authority on this.) With that caveat, here's what I found:

The comment above by @MichaelChernick seems to be right; the reason the confidence interval for your test includes zero is that the confidence interval is only approximately a 95% confidence interval. Google "misbehavior of binomial confidence intervals" (or something similar) for more.

I started looking around and found [this applet](https://www.r-bloggers.com/example-9-37-misbehavior-of-binomial-confidence-intervals/) if anyone is interested in just finding the 95% confidence interval for the difference of two proportions without messing around in R. At the bottom of the page containing the applet, they reference a [paper by Newcombe](http://vassarstats.net/prop2_ind.html) that appears to be widely accepted as the best way to calculate CIs for a difference of proportions (specifically, his method #10.)

I looked at the paper and couldn't really do the math. There are a few R packages that claim to implement this method but the best one I found was the **Epi package**. I'll use your example to explain:

```
tab <- matrix(c(10,10,22,70), nrow = 2)
tab

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   10   22
[2,]   10   70
```

Fisher's Exact test will give you a precise p-value for your table. The problem is that the test statistic it uses is an odds ratio, so it's not good for calculating the difference of proportions or confidence intervals. It is good for p-values though, so use it to check the p-value:

```
fisher.test(tab)

Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  tab
p-value = 0.03
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 1.0 9.7
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
   3.1
```

So we have an exact p-value of 0.03 which is significant at the 0.05 level. Now look at the `twoby2()` function from the Epi package:

```
library(Epi)
twoby2(tab)

2 by 2 table analysis: 
------------------------------------------------------ 
Outcome   : Col 1 
Comparing : Row 1 vs. Row 2 

       Col 1 Col 2    P(Col 1) 95% conf. interval
Row 1    10    22        0.31     0.177     0.49
Row 2    10    70        0.12     0.069     0.22

                                    95% conf. interval
             Relative Risk:  2.50     1.152     5.43
         Sample Odds Ratio:  3.18     1.172     8.64
Conditional MLE Odds Ratio:  3.14     1.028     9.70
    Probability difference:  0.19     0.027     0.37

         Exact P-value: 0.028 
    Asymptotic P-value: 0.023 
------------------------------------------------------
```

Note that the results given include the following:

- Individual proportion estimates with 95% CI
- Difference of proportions (0.19) with a 95% CI that does not include zero. (Again, according to the authors this function uses the method described in the Newcombe paper)
- an Exact p-value (which matches Fisher's Exact p-value calculated earlier)
- an asymptotic p-value. In my particular problem, this p-value matched the one given by the `prop.test()` function. That is not the case here for some reason.

Hope this helps anyone else who may wind up here!

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer commenting on @gonfle, yet I can not because of my reputation. I would like to add that if anyone else has the problem "an asymptotic p-value. In my particular problem, this p-value matched the one given by the prop.test() function. That is not the case here for some reason." using the EpiR package and the epi.2by2() function can help. This function gives an asymptotic p-value that is identical to that obtained with prop.test(correct=FALSE). I could not anything on https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/epiR/versions/1.0-10/topics/epi.2by2 about wether it follows the Newcombe method, nevertheless the 95%CI it produces is identical to that of the Epi package twoby2() function, so it seems that it does follow the Newcombe method.